# Split file in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and would like to do this if anyone can give me example, would appreciate. If I have this file :

```
Row1_id ,  val11, val12 , val13  
Row2_id ,  val21, val22 , val23
```

I need to split it to 3 files. A file for each column plus the row id and tab separated For example file1 should be:

```
row1_id val11  
row2_id val21
```

and the third file3:

```
row1_id  val13  
row2_id  val23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example of how you can solve the problem in your question. In your real use case you will want to change the names of the output files.
I assume that your data is an object of class `data.frame` named `dat`.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20, z = 21:30)
filenames <- sprintf("file%02d.txt", 1:3)
lapply(seq_len(ncol(dat)), function(i)
        write.table(dat[i], filenames[i], sep = "\t"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have your data in R already, so created an example of your data in R in three steps:

```
Row1_id <- c("val11", "val12", "val13")
Row2_id <- c("val21", "val22", "val23")
data<-data.frame(rbind(Row1_id, Row2_id))
```

Now there is a data frame called "data" and it looks like this:

```
           X1    X2    X3
Row1_id val11 val12 val13
Row2_id val21 val22 val23
```

An easy way to select columns is by applying "select" function from dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- select(data, X1)
df2 <- select(data, X2)
df3 <- select(data, X3)
```

Now there are 3 data frames, each containing just one column. For example, df2 looks like this:

```
           X2
Row1_id val12
Row2_id val22
```

Hope it helps!